# Manga about a crazy teenage boy

Tags: shamo

A few years ago I read a manga with the following features:

- The protagonist was a teenage boy, who grew up to an adolescent over the course of the story.
- He cruelly stabbed both his parents to death when he was young.
- He got sent to a juvenile detention centre, where he learned karate.
- When he got out he became a delinquent.
- Highly psychological and adult manga.

I am really curious as to how it ends, but I just can't remember the manga's name. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first result that came up when I googled "manga kill parents karate" was [Shamo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamo_%28manga%29). "It tells a story of a boy who killed his parents and turned himself into a cold-blooded martial artist." Is that the one you're looking for?

Comment: @Gao It's very likely Shamo's the manga I was looking for. I will only be able to make sure after work, but in the meantime, post it as an answer, since I think it will be correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Shamo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamo_%28manga%29)

[image]

Selected synopsis (emphasis by me):

> Ryo Narushima (成嶋 亮 Narushima Ryō?), a talented highschooler who was about to enter Tokyo University, the most prestigious university in Japan, **killed his parents** before his successful life could begin. [...] The **16-year-old** bookworm murderer was convicted and **sent to a reformatory** where he was gang raped by other boys. Kenji Kurokawa (黒川健児 Kurokawa Kenji?), a jailed man who nearly assassinated Japanese Prime Minister decades ago, was sent to the reformatory to **teach the youngsters karate** every week. [...] Ryo returns to society with the mindset of gaining strength so as to survive and never be a victim again.

Of interesting note is that

> This story was inspired by the Kobe child murders of 1997 that a 14-year-old "Boy A" ("Shōnen A") killed and decapitated several children.

The plot and settings somehow reminded me of *[Rainbow](http://myanimelist.net/manga/7482/Rainbow:_Nisha_Rokubou_no_Shichinin)*, which tells the story of 7 teenage delinquents, their lives in the reformatory, and their encounters in the real world outside. One of the seven killed his father (if memory serves), another went searching for his sister, and yet another learned boxing while in the reformatory, all very similar to what the protagonist Ryo in Shamo did.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Shamo was indeed the manga I was looking for, furthermore, I think I will give Rainbow a try as well. Looks really interesting!